# cannot access cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature - Selenium Test

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I have a problem when try to run my code, since the runner created!
When running it, it shows me the message:

java: cannot access cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature
class file for cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature not found

**My feature:**

```
Feature: LoginFeature
This feature is responsible for testing all the scenarios for Login application
Scenario: Create a new Login with correct username and password
Given I ensure application opened
When I enter Username and Password
  |UserName                   |Password    |
  |TEST |TEST |
Then I click login button
Then I should see the Campaign page displayed
```

**My Runner file:**

```
package com.crm.test.runner;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/com/crm/test/features"}, glue = 
{"src/test/com/crm/test/steps"})
public class TestRunner {

private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUpClass(){
    testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
}

@Test(dataProvider = "features")
public void runTest(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeatureWrapper){
    testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeatureWrapper.getCucumberFeature());
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] features(){
    return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterClass(){
    testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
}
}
```

**Error Log**

```
/Users/diegohidalgo/IdeaProjects/CRMFramework/src/test/com/crm/test/runner/TestRunner.java:24:83
java: cannot access cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature
class file for cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature not found
```

Comment: The usual reason for this problem is that the java file with CucumberOptions is not in the right path/package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 'import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;' Junit options in TestNG-Cucumber

Change the import to **'import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;**